# How to display pop up with textbox and button when click on button in jsf?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to display pop up dialog box with input box and button when click on Button. Here is my implementation...

```
                   <h:form name="calcDistanceform" widgetVar="selectedRowValuesDlg" style="margin:5px;" >

                                <h:inputText name="sourceDistance" value="#{searchController.sourceDistance}" /> 

                                <h:commandButton  value="Caliculate" class="popdistance" id="popdistancecalc" style="background-color:red;font-size:10px;font-weight:600">

                                   <p:ajax process="@this" update=""  listener="#{searchController.calculateDistance}"  />

                                </h:commandButton>

                </h:form>


                <p:commandLink value="Get Distance"  actionListener="#{searchController.onDistanceClick}"  oncomplete="PF('selectedRowValuesDlg').show();"  process="@this">        
                        <f:attribute name="clinic" value="#{clinic}"/>
                </p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Did you honestly not find this in the PrimeFaces showcase or by using google?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `p:dialog` component http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml

```
<p:dialog header="My Dialog" widgetVar="selectedRowValuesDlg">
    <h:form name="calcDistanceform" style="margin:5px;" >
         <h:inputText name="sourceDistance" value="#{searchController.sourceDistance}" /> 

         <h:commandButton value="Caliculate" class="popdistance" id="popdistancecalc" style="background-color:red;font-size:10px;font-weight:600" action="#{searchController.calculateDistance}" update="@form" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>

<p:commandLink value="Get Distance" actionListener="#{searchController.onDistanceClick}"  oncomplete="PF('selectedRowValuesDlg').show()"  process="@this">        
      <f:attribute name="clinic" value="#{clinic}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```